# How to change xml attribute while deserialization with xmlserializer c#?

Tags: c#, xml, xmlserializer

Is there any way of modifying attribute value when deserializing xml using XmlSerializer?

For instance, I have such xml:

```
<chunkList>
   <chunk id="ch1" type="p">
      <sentence id="s1">
         <tok>
            <orth>XXX</orth>
            <lex disamb="1">
               <base>XXX</base>
               <ctag>subst:sg:nom:f</ctag>
            </lex>
         </tok>
      </sentence>
   </chunk>
</chunkList>
```

I want to deserialize `chunk` element into `Chunk` class and set attribute `id="ch1"` to `Id` property - is there any way of trimming this `ch` substring and asigning number `1` to property of type int?

```
[XmlAttribute("id")] //maybe there is some attribute to achive this?
public int Id { get; set; }
```

I have read some of [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer?view=net-5.0) documentation but didn't found any solution.

Comment: implement the `IXmlSerializable` interface and define your own logic for `XmlSerializer` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable

Answer (score 2):

There is no elegant way to achieve this using a single attribute.  The only way I know to achieve the desired result is to make use of [XmlIgnore] and to create a second property specifically for the stringified xml ID, and a localized converter property for your internal integer value. Some along the lines of:

```
[XmlAttribute("id")] 
public string _id_xml {get; set;}

 [XmlIgnore]
 public int Id {
        // convert local copy of xml attribute value to/from int.
        get => int.Parse(_id_xml.Replace("ch",""));
        set => _id_xml = $"ch{value}";
   }
```

*My converter here is very basic and clearly you will need to improve it and consider error handling.*

The serializer will operate against the [XmlAttribute] as normal, but pass over the [XmlIgnore].  Your c# code could use either.
Unfortunately, the XmlSerializer requires public properties, so you can not hide the **_id_xml** property from your code, but you could use [Obsolete] to signal a warning in the compiler.

You could do the conversion to/from int with the _id_xml getter & setter, but doing this could be problematic when managing errors during serialization.